# Copying values across a dynamic column and row range

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that:

- copies the column headings (in row 1) from column C across to the second last column
- pastes these column headings in row 1 in the column 2 across from the last column with data
- pastes the column headings alongside each row of data through to the bottom row

  ```
  Sub GLDR()

  'use End(xlUp) to determine Last Row with Data, in column A of the GLDRYYPP tab
  Dim lastRowDR As Long
  lastRowDR = Sheets("GLDRYYPP").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  'copy the cost type categories and paste alongside the cost centres
  CTNameCol = "S2:AF" & lastRowDR

  Sheets("GLDRYYPP").Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, -1)).Copy
  Sheets("GLDRYYPP").Paste Destination:=Sheets("GLDRYYPP").Range("C1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 2)
  Sheets("GLDRYYPP").Range(Range("C1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 2), Range("C1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 2).End(xlToRight)).Copy

  Sheets("GLDRYYPP").Paste Destination:=Sheets("GLDRYYPP").Range(CTNameCol)

  End Sub
  ```

The first two steps have been set to be dynamic for any additional columns added but I am having trouble writing some code that will paste the data through to the bottom row. As you can see the range "S2:AF(last row)" has been written to make use of the result from the lastRowDR dimension.

Is there a way to write the code which will make the copy dynamic across the columns and rows?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to write the code which will make the copy dynamic across the columns and rows.  What you need to do is to identify a distinct quality about  the cost centres so that you locate it using something like `ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(Txt)`.
Then you'll be able to determine what CTNameCol should be. There is some helpful info here: [Range.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).

If you add add a picture of your spreadsheet I will update this answer with more precise information.